# Failed to exchange a code for an access token for creating zendesk instance in cloud element through API

Tags: oauth-2.0, cloud, instance, zendesk-api

Please help to create zendesk instance in cloud element by 3rd party api call
Created Zendesk account [Created & configure as per in Link](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203663836-Using-OAuth-authentication-with-your-application)

Succesfully got Elements OAuth Information

```js
{
  "oauthUrl": "https://yoursubdoamin.zendesk.com/oauth/authorizations/new?response_type=code&client_id=zendesk_unique_identifier&redirect_uri=http://www.my_cool_app.com/auth&scope=read write&state=zendesk",
  "element": "zendesk"
}
```

Getting error in API

```
curl -X POST
-H 'Authorization: User <INSERT_USER_SECRET>, Organization <INSERT_ORGANIZATION_SECRET>'
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
-d @instance.json
'https://api.cloud-elements.com/elements/api-v2/instances'
```

instance.json

```js
{
  "element": {
    "key": "zendesk"
  },
  "providerData": {
    "code": "Code on Return the URL"
  },
  "configuration": {
    "oauth.api.key": "<INSERT_ZENDESK_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER>",
    "oauth.api.secret": "<INSERT_ZENDESK_CLIENT_SECRET>",
    "oauth.callback.url": "https://www.my_cool_app.com",
    "zendesk.subdomain": "<INSERT_ZENDESK_SUB_DOMAIN>"
  },
  "tags": [
    "<INSERT_TAGS>"
  ],
  "name": "<INSERT_INSTANCE_NAME>"
}
```

Getting error "Failed to exchange a code for an access token"

Comment: it is not clear from your question at which step do you stumble.

Comment: i goted error while creating zendesk instance via cloud element  api

Answer (score 0):

This might be because, you might not have registered an app with zendesk to get back the access token. This can also happen if your `element` in Cloud Elements is corrupted, make sure you are using the inbuild element instance. Still if you are facing the issue, please mention the steps you followed